# php form get parameters from url and store it until the final page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, get

I wrote a simple PHP survey application about movies and I am using one of the crowdsourcing services to collect data. In order to verify and rate workers, I have to generate VCODE ([https://microworkers.com/vcode.php](https://www.microworkers.com/login.php)) in the final page and so workers can submit it as their proof of finishing my task.

I have to give this URL to users: [http://www.yourwebsite.com/start.php?campaign={{CAMP_ID}}&worker={{MW_ID}}](https://monsterhost.com/?campaign=A928HDI22&worker=XC900129)

and user will see the URL like this:(numbers are inserted by the crowdsourcing site and worker_Id is unique for each worker)
http://www.yourwebsite.com/start.php?campaign=AB1234&worker=CD456

**Now my problem:** I need to get the parameters (campaign and worker Ids) and keep them through to the end of the survey. Only in this way, my website would be able to generate the correct VCode which will be accepted by the
crowdsourcing system.
But I don't know why I get only `NULL` values.

This is how I collected the values on the first index.php page:

```
$Campaign_id = $_GET["campaign"];
$Worker_id = $_GET["worker"];
```

and then after this page there is another php page where I insert login values (such as email or password), I wrote:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MEMBER (worker_Id, password, email, confirmcode) VALUES (:worker_Id, :password, :email, :confirmcode)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':password' => $password, ':email' => $emailTrimmed, ':confirmcode' => $activation, 'worker_Id' => $Worker_id));
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

But when I check the DB, it inserted NULL for worker_Id.

I know my code has some problems, because in my first page I used some forms and all of them use "post" method. One of these form is for login and when user click "login", the action is "sendEmail.php" page in which I insert users' info (such as email, pass and worker_Id in the DB). I don't know the problem is because my method is post and I used _GET? if yes, what should I do, because I think I should not change post to get, since I have to get password for which "post" is recommended. Or, if the problem is because I had to write "$Worker_id = $_GET["worker"]; in index page?

I am really confused, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: is it really `worker_Id` and not `worker_id` ? some sort of standard to your var names would help

Comment: @Dagon: In my table, I named it worker_Id, but I stored it in Worker_id variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like - but I may be wrong so please clarify any incorrect assumptions - but it looks like there are potentially several issues here:

- Get and post are different. Use `$_REQUEST['var']` to select GET or POST (I think POST overwrites GET values in this situation, if both are supplied)
- In you are reloading your index.php page several times for several stages of the survey then each time you reload the values will need to be recreated from $_GET / $_POST / $_SESSION / $_COOKIE data, I recommend:

  - Either Setting the captured `$_REQUEST['worker']` / `$_REQUEST['campaign']` values into hidden fields in the survey form on each stage so they're (re)submitted each time a new page is reached, and passed along the process from start to finish, remember using the `$_REQUEST` value will always pick up *both/either* `$_GET` and `$_POST` data.
  - Or, As soon as the values are captured (from your original/first `$_GET` clause) then set them as `$_SESSION` variables and then call these on the final stage.

As a Wider aspect, run some IF queries to check that database functionality is only called if the `$_REQUEST` (or `$_SESSION`, if that path is chosen) values are set and/or non-empty.

It would be useful for debugging to output these values on each stage/page of the process to see where these values are "dropped". Such as using

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

We would need to see a more complete view of the details of your PHP page to give you more specific advice, but in general check your PHP error log file (don't know, try `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);` at the top of your page and/or check the various PHP error log questions on Stackoverflow, there are many). And see if your error log comes back with a SQL specific error such as your SQL worker_Id column is infact numeric auto-increment whereas your given example data is alphanumeric. This will causes an error and SQL will not write the data row.

Anyhow, good luck,

PS -> As a personal note I prefer to use single quotes for declaring array values

EdIT: Adding Hidden values to Forms:

```
<form>
....
<input type="hidden" name="worker" value="<?php print $Worker_id;?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="campaign" value="<?php print $Campaign_id;?>" >
... 
</form>
```

From this any page that loads either the original $_GET or any form data (including the page loading the example form above) can have the $_GET/$_POST replaced with :

```
$Campaign_id = $_REQUEST['campaign'];
$Worker_id = $_REQUEST['worker'];
```

This means that the forms will send the data when the form is submitted and you do not need to add GET values to the form submission field specified in `<form action="here">`

Comment: Thanks for a complete explanation,  I will try and let you know. thank you :)

Comment: Re-reading your question again and again it appears to me most likely that you have saved the values to a variable on the first page and then not resaved them to new variables when new pages are loaded. each page in PHP is completely independant of any other page in it's collection of variables, unless expressly passed via the array types mentioned in my answer. @mOna

Comment: My first page (index.php) contains 2 forms. one of the form which is sendEmail.php is the one I insert values in DB. In this page I included another php page which is checkEmail.php in which I wrote $_GET['worker'].. I think maybe I had to write it in index.php??!

Comment: Yes. Or use `$_REQUEST` on *every page that you load*, to collect the data from each page preceeding it, think of it as basketball, each time you pass the ball someone else has to catch it - to catch the variable each time a new page loads involves setting the value of the variable on each new page as being a `$_GET` / `$_POST` / `$_REQUEST` / `$_SESSION` value. @mOna

Comment: well this is where the lack of information limits what I can say, how many pages do you have? - as I have explained, you can use `$_REQUEST` on any / every page as it will collect GET and POST data. You can use SESSION if you have experience with using PHP session, because you can use it at the first page and then just call it up at the last page.

Comment: I just found a way that worked! I just changed the form action url in index.php, so I changed `<form class="test" id="1234" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="sendEmail.php">` to `<form class="test" id="1234" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://polimovie.deib.polimi.it/Version3/sendEmail.php?campaign=AB1234&worker=CD4567">` and it inserted the worker_Id: CD4567 in DB.

Comment: But actually I am not sure if it was the correct way??

Comment: What you did there, @mOna was add GET values to the POST form, which does work but can be more easily copied and forged etc. But if it works, that's good. A neater - more correct way of doing it is to use "hidden HTML form inputs" to save the values into the form, and then replace all your `$_GET` calls with `$_REQUEST` and that would also work. Shall I add this to my answer?

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the correct way. Actually, I am not sure if I can use $_REQUEST, because in their website, here, (https://microworkers.com/vcode.php) they wrote using $_GET, also I have never user $_REQEST before. but could I use "hidden html form inputs" in my first index.php page and then in sendEmail.php page, I use $_POST for email and password and $_GET for worker_id and campaign_Id ?

Comment: @mOna $_REQUEST automatically takes GET/POST data, it means you don't have to test for either one or the other but it automatically takes both into one variable. Please read http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php. It's a shortcut superglobal variable. :-)

Comment: If you save data into a form the data is automatically passed to the next page on form submission as "POST" data as long as the form is submitted with POST method, which yours is. That is the only change, aside from hiding the data from the page URL and the browser history of the user.

Comment: but if I save data into a form, as you said it hides data from URL. in this case, how the crowdsourcing website can replace tag {{CAMP_ID}} with actual Campaign ID and {{MW_ID}} with Worker ID ?? because the actual URL that I provide for workers is : http://polimovie.deib.polimi.it/Version3?campaign={{CAMP_ID}}&worker={{MW_ID}}, now I just test with some parameters only for test.

Comment: thanks for your edit and complete answer. just one more question: If I add hidden input and use $_REQUEST for worker_id and campaign_id as you suggested, should I still user $_POST for email and password or $_REQUST for all of them?

Comment: @mOna I think you are confused. When the crowdsourcing URL links to your FIRST page, it sends you data - worker and campaign IDs, via GET variables, from then on, you can pass these values from page to page however you like, GET or POST or whatever - that's your choice. As it is within your website and not related to the crowdsourcing website, as far as I understand your question. When you want to return to the other website and if you need to return with these variables then you have to pass them back in the GET request.

Comment: re: POST, yes, data you know is ONLY sent via a form should ONLY be collected as a $_POST variable, but the same data will always be copied into the REQUEST data. REQUEST = POST and GET data, they're not different they're the same thing (as good as, in this context)

Comment: Thank YOU! you are right I was confused, but you explained very well. It worked by putting these lines in my form: `<input type="hidden" name="worker" value="<?php echo $_GET['worker'];?>" >
  <input type="hidden" name="campaign" value="<?php echo $_GET['campaign'];?>" >` , Then in the other page, I used them by : `$Campaign_id = $_REQUEST['campaign'];
$Worker_id = $_REQUEST['worker'];`